# discord.py Cooldown error doesn't allow other errors to be raised

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have this code for cooldowns and to send the error to the user. This is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):

        if error.retry_after>3600:
            embed=discord.Embed(title='Cooldown!', description=f"This command can be used in **{round(error.retry_after/3600)}h**   !".format(error.retry_after))
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return


        if error.retry_after>60:
            embed=discord.Embed(title='Cooldown!', description=f"This command can be used in **{round(error.retry_after/60)}m**!".format(error.retry_after))
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return

        else:
            embed=discord.Embed(title='Cooldown!', description=f"This command can be used in **{round(error.retry_after)}s**!".format(error.retry_after))
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

But when i add this, other errors such as MissingRequirements don't get raised in the terminal in Visual Studio Code. Does anyone know why or how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error Handler checks if the error is the CommandOnCooldown error. If it isnt, the error gets ignored. Add another else statement:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):

         if error.retry_after>3600:
         ....

         else:
         ....
    else:
         Stuff the bot should do on a different error come here
```